# Why does this onTouchListener throw NullPointerException?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I dont undestand,   i have used this same code in main activity from the same app, and worked well. But when i use this in other activity, it throws me NullPointer.... Why is this?

```
     private TextView drag_txtSeconds; 

     @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drag_layout); 

       drag_txtSeconds = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtSeconds); 

       drag_txtSeconds.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {
                return true; 
            }});
         }
```

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: drag_txtSeconds is null?

Comment: what is drah_txtSeconds ? where you are defining it please put that code.it seems it is null.

Comment: Yeah,its true,i should put most of my code here ... i will do it

Comment: It is directly copied from the activity...

Comment: make sure your drag_layout has a textview with id TxtSeconds.

Comment: Ok, it was fault of mine, the problem was this: `drag_txtSeconds = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtSeconds);` was wrong, I should put ` drag_txtSeconds = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.drag_TxtSeconds);`.... Problem solved, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your file `drag_layout` has a `TextView` with the attribute:

```
android:id="@+id/TxtSeconds"
```

This is case sensitive, and may be due to the capital letters, try using all lowercase in the layout and in your code.